# Change data dir of mysql on RHEL 6.6

Tags: mysql, redhat

I was trying to change the data_dir of mysql.
So I did

1. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. change the data entry in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to the new location
3. sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

It failed. The log says

```
151201 15:43:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151201 15:43:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
151201 16:06:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /data/data_raid5_0/mysql
151201 16:06:15 [Warning] Can't create test file /data/data_raid5_0/mysql/PEC630.lower-test
151201 16:06:15 [Warning] Can't create test file /data/data_raid5_0/mysql/PEC630.lower-test
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/data/data_raid5_0/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
151201 16:06:15 [ERROR] Aborting

151201 16:06:15 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

151201 16:06:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I first thought it was write permission issue, but after fixing it, I still get the same error in log.

Could anyone give me some suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error may be due to the fact that you didn't restore the correct SELinux context to the MySQL new datadir.  Try this command:

```
chcon -R --reference=/var/lib/mysql/ /data/data_raid5_0/mysql/
```

P.S.: The MySQL config file is `/etc/my.cnf`, not `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, but I assume this is just a typo.